# How to move a WordPress Localhost straight to an online site?

Tags: localhost, hosting

I have read several guides including [this one](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/) which talk about creating a live server which is hosted.

I don't require a custom domain and are happy having it named `mysite.wordpress.com.` If I am moving it from localhost how can I upload this using the WordPress online editor so that my site can be live?

I would like to do this for free, which is why I am not going with a custom domain.

Is it possible, or do I have to hos the site under a custom domain? If this is the case do I have to copy and paste all content individually to my WordPress online editor from the installed localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing WordPress.com and WordPress.org. The .org is what is used for hosting your own WordPress website on your hosting provider.

The .com is hosting your website using WordPress.com's systems. There are some major differences between the two and it's critical that you understand them.

First and foremost hosting on .com has severe restrictions on the themes and plugins that you can use. Ultimately you are limited to what is approved by WordPress.com.

Hosting your own domain allows you much more control over your website, the themes, and plugins you can use.

To my knowledge, there is no way to upload your locally developed website to WordPress.com. You can however deploy it to your own hosting provider.